# SocketTimeoutException in android-socket Communication

Tags: android, sockets, exception

I'm trying to connect my 'Galaxy S' to my Panasonic PLC(or even other PC itself) but I always get an SocketTimeoutException. My android version is 2.3.3:

IP-PLC: 192.168.2.99

IP-GalaxyS: I don't know how to check it

Mask of the network: 255.255.255.0

The PLC is connected directly with the wi-fi router, and I connect my cell phone to this network.

```
package com.example.communication;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;

import android.util.Log;

public class TryConnection implements Runnable {    
public void run() {
    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.2.99");
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 9094);
        Log.e("SUCESS", "SUCESS");
    } catch(SocketTimeoutException e) {
        Log.e("SOCKET TIMEOUT", "SOCKET TIMEOUT", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {       
        Log.e("CONNECTION ", " ERROR", e);
    }       
}
```

and my MainActivity Class:

```
package com.example.communication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void sendTag(View view) {        
    TryConnection tryconnection = new TryConnection();
    Thread thread = new Thread(tryconnection);
    thread.start();
}
}
```

Do you have any idea for why is it happening ?

Comment: Nothing is listening on the other side? No network access to `192.168.2.99`?

Comment: Yes, it's listening, the PLC is working fine, when I try to connect and send data direct from PC it works perfectly.

Comment: What are the network settings (IPs/masks/routes) on the devices/PCs involved?

Comment: You get this when connecting, or when receiving?

Comment: I get this error while connecting, this simple code above gives the timeout, I cant even connect to the device:

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me also, restarted eclipse to resolve the issue.